# how to Make the call back to run only once scroll Trigger GSAP?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, gsap

I am using the GSAP animation library for adding scroll animation to the website, and for that, I have a custom Callback `onEnter:()`  (at the bottom of the page on the green box "C" {for that please check the code}) it runs the function and shows the message in the console once it enters the viewport but if I again go up and scroll down this functions runs again  I want this function to run only once in spite the user is scrolling up and down many times it has to run a single time.

I tried to find the answer to this question all over the internet even on the GSAP forums but didn't get any idea So can anyone please tell me how I can do that?

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.to(".c",{
  scrollTrigger:{
    trigger:".c",
    onEnter:test,
    start:"top center",
    markers:true,
  },
  x:400,
  rotation:300,
  immediateRender: true,
  duration:3
})

function test(){
  console.log("I am entered")
}
```

```css
.sc-div{
    height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.a{
  background:red;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.b{
  background: yellow;
}
.c{
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}

.mt{
  margin-top:500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="a sc-div">A</div>
  <div class="b sc-div mt">B</div>
  <div class="c sc-div mt">C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! how to do this I just have to add the `once: true` property in the Scroll trigger Object and it will gonna run only once even after I Scroll multiple times in the viewport